# What is nimbus.task.timeout.secs property is storm

Tags: apache-storm

What is `nimbus.task.timeout.secs` property is storm. How it is different from `topology.message.timeout.secs`.

Answer (score 3):

See the below definitions from the code base.

**nimbus.task.timeout.secs** - [see here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/Config.java#L261)

> How long without heartbeating a task can go before nimbus will
>   consider the task dead and reassign it to another location.

**topology.message.timeout.secs** -  [see here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/Config.java#L573)

> The maximum amount of time given to the topology to fully process a
>   message emitted by a spout. If the message is not acked within this
>   time frame, Storm will fail the message on the spout. Some spouts
>   implementations will then replay the message at a later time.

Have a look at [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/eiichirouchiumi/storm-anatomy) on storm internals.